# Convert lat and lon to geoshape point in logstash conf?

Tags: logstash

How to stash input values such as lat and lon to create geoshape point before output to elasticsearch
example 
need to output to elasticsearch as 
       "location": {
            "type": "point",
            "coordinates": [-84.636,33.33]
          }
For generating the above what code what filter should add in logstash conf file?

Answer (score 0):

guys got the answer for this after a long search. its like this 
If you want to stash lat lon in to elasticsearch which already has mapping as

```
"location": {
            "type": "geo_shape"
          }
```

On your conf file in logstash
you will have to use the filter mutate

```
mutate {
     add_field => { "[location][type]" => "point"
                    "[location][coordinates]" => ["%{LocationDataLng}",
                    "%{LocationDataLat}"]
     }
   }
```